Prove a lemma for the formulas for linear probing(An exercise from the book by Knuth)
The expected number of probes for linear probing is:
Successful search: $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{1-\alpha}\right)$
Unsuccessful search: $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{(1-\alpha)^2}\right)$
I found a proof on The Art Of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth. But the math is quite overhead for me. Here are the defined functions:
$$f(m,n):=\left(1-\dfrac{n}{m}\right)m^n$$
where $f(0,0)=1$ by convention.
$$g(m,n,k):=\binom{n}{k}f(k+1, k)f(m-k-1,n-k)$$ $$=\binom{n}{k}(k+1)^{k-1}(m-k-1)^{n-k-1}(m-n-1)$$
$$p(m,n,k):=\dfrac{\mathop{\sum}_{j=k}^{n}g(m,n,j)}{m^n}$$
Then the book says in the answer to exercise 27 of 6.4 that $m^n\mathop{\sum}_{k= 0}^{n}(k+1)p(m,n,k)=\mathop{\sum}_{k=0}^n\binom{k+2}{2}g(m,n,k)$
I tried many times to get this but failed.
(The lemma that I want to prove is Theorem K in 6.4 of Volume 3.)

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  His name is Knuth

I assume the part which is a problem is why $$\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)\sum_{j=k}^n g(m,n,j) = \sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)\frac{k+2}2g(m,n,k)?$$ The rest of it is pretty standard algebra. And does that sum over $k$ has some implicit upper limit, or is it supposed to be to $\infty$?

@PaulSinclair Thank you for pointing out that. Yes, this is the key problem. And I've modified the index of the summation to make it more clear.

The definition of $g(m,n,k)$ is immaterial here. For any sequence $\{g_k\}_{k=0}^n$ and defining $P_k = \sum_{j=k}^n g_k$ (So $P_k \equiv m^np(m,n,k)$), we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1) P_k = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=k}^n (k+1)g_j=\sum_{j=0}^n g_j\sum_{k=0}^j(k+1) = \sum_{j=0}^ng_j\binom{j+2}2$$
Considering $k$ as the $x$ coordinate, $j$ as the $y$ coordinate, the summation by $k$ then by $j$ is over all $(k,j)$ pairs in the $n \times n$ square which are on or above the diagonal. The sum organizes by $k$ first and iterates through the pairs $(k,k)$ to $(k, n)$. Transposing the sums is organizing by $j$ first, and for each $j$, iterating from $(0, j)$ to $(j,j)$. Either way includes every pair on or above the diagonal exactly once.
